# MappingException with hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a maven project that I am using with `hibernate-core 4.2.3.Final`. I have followed the advice provided here:

[Where to place hibernate config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677783/where-to-place-hibernate-cfg-xml)

[Hibernate Tutorial - Where to put Mapping File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947542/hibernate-tutorial-where-to-put-mapping-file)

and the config file in `src/main/resources` looks like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/justHibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">12345</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <mapping resource="com/mycompany/app/model/Movie.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

while the mapping file is within the package `com.mycompany.app.model` alongside the `Movie` class:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mycompany.app.model.Movie" table="Movies">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="title" column="title"/>
        <property name="director" column="director"/>
        <property name="synopsis" column="synopsis"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Exception**

The configuration cannot find the mapping file.

```
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/mycompany/app/model/Movie.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/mycompany/app/model/Movie.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:738)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2139)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2072)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1987)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1966)
    at com.mycompany.app.MovieManager.initSessionFactory(MovieManager.java:22)
    at com.mycompany.app.MovieManager.<init>(MovieManager.java:17)
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:27)
```

Comment: `com/mycompany/app/model/Movie.hbm.xml not found` means either file is missing or file is misplaced meaning path might be wrong

Comment: where did you place `Movie.hbm.xml` ? is it under `src` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `Movie.hbm.xml` under `src/main/resources` and change path in your config file as follows,

```
<mapping resource="Movie.hbm.xml" />
```

Hope this helps.